# I am being told conflicting resolutions for fixing a closed question, what should I do?

Tags: support, status-deferred, closed-questions, questions

I had a [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/637288/what-would-you-see-dropping-an-sufficiently-strong-chain-with-substantial-length) that was closed, and I was given the following instructions:

[image]

Those questions listed did not provide me with the answer to my question, so I followed the advice and opened a new [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/637330/how-do-you-reconcile-issues-of-watching-a-chain-fall-toward-a-black-hole) that I completely reformatted.

This was then in turn closed as a duplicate of my original question.

[image]

I was then given the following instructions by a moderator:

[image]

I just want to ask this question, what should I do?

Comment: In the meantime, I'm updating my original question with the content of the second one I opened, hoping that will show it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Hi Michael King -- revising the original is the right approach given how things have always worked, and the "new question" phrasing is perhaps not the best. I've tagged it for SE to review so they can add it as another data point to consider how to word those closures. So thanks for reporting it, and thanks for your patience (and for revising the original question to clarify how it's unique from the duplicates)!

Comment: @tpg2114 thanks for the info! I’m glad the revision worked! Thanks

Comment: What a mess. I have to ask: what does the “ask a new one” link actually do?

Comment: @G.Smith It links to the [page to ask a new question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if I remember correctly. Somewhat annoyingly, I (as a moderator) cannot see the same close banner than the question owner sees when a question is closed as a duplicate. Makes providing support interesting.

Comment: @tpg2114 I have seen several members complain about being instructed to post a new question, and then being told they shouldn’t have. But I think this is the first time I have seen the actual evidence. (Thank you, Michael King!) Let’s either fix this or change our policy. We look like we don’t know what we are doing.

Comment: @G.Smith No disagreement from me there! With the status review tag, it puts the post on SE's issue tracker so the Community Management team can discuss. They may decide to change the wording of the notice, in which case problem solved! Or they may decide that it should stay the way it is, in which case we should update how we respond/treat re-posts of the same or very similar questions.

Comment: @G.Smith and I'm glad I could help! Let me know if you need anything else from me. And also thanks for the support on getting my original question reopened tpg.

Comment: FWIW, the same issue appeared [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/640909/2451), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645105/2451), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/661464/2451), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/734973/2451).

Comment: I've [tag:status-deferred] this; please follow [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364874/208518) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like SE doesn't think this is a problem. I suggest you [take a look at their response to this issue.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364874/294226)

Vote your conscience and leave a comment there.